# When casting a datetime as date, why does SQLite3 only return the year and not the full date?

Tags: sqlite, date, datetime, casting, type-conversion

I know that you can cast a datetime to date using the [date() function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
sqlite> select date('2000-01-01 10:00:00');
2000-01-01
```

But why does [SQLite3's cast expression](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#castexpr) such as in

```
sqlite> select cast('2000-01-01 10:00:00' as date);
2000
```

only return the year?

Even using an explicit datetime() setup solely returns the year:

```
sqlite> select cast(datetime('2000-01-01 10:00:00') as date);
2000
```

Or:

```
sqlite> select cast(datetime('now') as date);
2019
```

Looking at Postgresql, it resolves both properly:

```
postgresql> select date('2000-01-01 10:00:00');
2000-01-01

postgresql> select cast('2000-01-01 10:00:00' as date);
2000-01-01
```

What's the technical explanation for SQLite3's – to me unexpected – behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For SQLite there is no `Date` datatype. As mentioned in their documentation here: https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

What you use as `Date` is actually `TEXT`.

You can check that:

```
select typeof(datetime('now'));
```

returns:

```
text
```

And:

```
select typeof(cast(datetime('now') as date));
```

returns:

```
integer
```

So the result of `cast('2000-01-01 10:00:00' as date)` is an integer and it's the same 
integer that you get by:

```
select '2000-01-01 10:00:00' + 0
```

when SQLite implicitly converts `'2000-01-01 10:00:00'` to `2000` in order to use it in a mathematical operation.
In the case of dates it happens to be the numeric value of the year, but in general SQLite returns the longest substring of the TEXT, starting from the 1st character, that can be represented as an integer.
So for `'2000-01-01 10:00:00'` it's the substring until the 1st `-`, which is the year.

Comment: As for *why* it converts to an integer - [... the storage class of the result is determined by applying the rules for determining column affinity to the type-name](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html). `date` has the default numeric affinity per the rules in the datatype documentation.

Comment: You had that url in the first paragraph; I didn't see the point in repeating it in a comment.